# Is it meaningful to attribute emotions to an organization?

Tags: academic-research, empathy

I recently found myself puzzled over the general behavior of an organization as it related to taking official actions that I thought provided little (if any) benefit at a high cost to the organization itself. Basically, I was seeing "corporate self-harm" if you can imagine it that way. To try to understand this behavior, I found myself attempting to attribute emotions such as fear or sadness to the organization as a collective whole rather than to individual actors within that organization who might have participated in the decisions in question.

Of course, it soon occurred to me that organizations (whether formal or informal in nature) do not have emotions per se but may act on the emotions of those who control or influence them. After that, it occurred to me that even though organizations don't literally feel emotions, attributing emotions to them as a form of empathy might actually be a viable model to understand their behavior and relate better to them.

Examples of attributing emotions to organizations:

- The Bakersville Coalition of Independent Restaurants is excited about falling beef prices.
- The Seventh Avenue Baptist Church is saddened by the loss of its pastor.
- The City Council is afraid of rising river levels.
- Bank of America is perplexed at the obfuscated paperwork my lawyer sent them.
- The Marketing Division of the Sirius Cybernetics Corporation is terrified of being the first against the wall when the revolution comes.
- The Marketing Division of the Sirius Cybernetics Corporation feels empowered over their latest project.
- Conglom-O is struggling with guilt for their falsifications of their 2022 Q1 earnings statement.

The critical distinction here is that an emotion is being attributed to the organization rather than independent participants. For example, one individual member of the City Council might not be experiencing the emotion of fear in a personal psychological sense, but there is definitely an "air of fear" in the organization and collective actions taken by the organization will arguably be colored by the emotion of fear.

To that end, is there any research on whether attributing emotions to organizations as a whole (as opposed to empathizing independently with each participant in the organization) is a useful model in understanding or relating to organizations? Of course, my instinct is to say "yes, it could be a useful model sometimes but other times might not be", but what I'm interested in is if this has been studied in any formal way.

I'm finding many articles about managing individual emotions in a team environment (e.g. managing a grief-stricken employee) but not about collective attribution of emotion (e.g. grief-stricken teams, shy churches, an agitated fraternity, an unsure platoon, a perplexed third shift, or an oil company racked with guilt).

Comment: It's called anthropomorphism, and I'm not sure if that's an interpersonal skill as defined in the [help/on-topic]: "the behaviours that are used to interact *with other people*" (emphasis mine). Anthropomorphism is attributing human traits to *non-human* entities, and so isn't a behavior used to interact *with other people*.

Comment: I'm not seeing this as IPS, but a quick LMGTFY gives [lots of answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=academic+studies+about+anthropomorphism) about what you seem to seek. Helpful?